# Strawberry flowers are too close to the crown

Tags: strawberries

Flowers on my strawberries are growing very close to the crown, I can't even see their stems. Is it normal? Can the stems still get longer?

It's currently still quite cold outside (between 0 and -5°C at night), so I'm afraid that this is caused by low temperatures.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it 100% answers the question, but it looks like stems can still grow even with flowers on them. Now my strawberry looks like this, the stems got much longer.

[image]

It's still unclear whether it had anything to do with the cold, but that sounds like the most reasonable explanation (since warm temperatures make plants grow faster).